# How does the "Require TLS" option work in AWS SES receipt rules ( for incoming emails )?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, tls1.2, amazon-ses

Ruleset case 1 :

1. Rule 1: Lambda Action ( Require TLS = true )
2. Rule 2: S3 Action ( Require TLS = true )

In this case, the incoming is email is bounced back with a msg -

> inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com said: 550 5.7.1 TLS
> required by recipient (in reply to RCPT TO command)

Now, when I updated the ruleset as below -
Ruleset case 2 :

1. Rule 1: Lambda Action ( Require TLS = true )
2. Rule 2: S3 Action ( Require TLS = false )

It worked just fine!

My thoughts are, Mail-Sender-Server to SES ( Lambda ) is TLS enabled. But, there onwards either by default, it is over TLS as it moves ahead to consequent rules in the ruleset, or it is not TLS enabled at all and there is some configuration required that I do not know. Please enlighten me.